# Method crashes when called from different view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am attempting to perform a segue after  a done button is pressed from a custom signature alertView. The segue works perfect if I call it from a button inside the same view, but when I call from my signature class, I get a crash that says:

```
    `'Receiver (<SuperSigApproveTableViewController: 0x79eea280>) has no segue with identifier 'approveSwap''
```

SignatureAlertViewController is the name of the class that calls the done method

```
- (IBAction)dismissAlertView:(id)sender {
[linerSig sendSigImageToServer];
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[sp sendToPDF];}];
}
```

inside the completion block is the method I am trying to call which is located inside of SuperSigApproveTableViewController

```
-(void)sendToPDF {
NSLog(@"sendtopdf");
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"approveSwap" sender: self];
}
```

I have alloc and init the SuperSigApproveTableView in the viewDidLoad method of SignatureAlertViewController. I am not sure why it is crashing does anyone have any clues?

Comment: How are you defining sp? Also, do you get an error message with the crash?

Comment: The presenting ViewController is the same with SuperSigApproveTableView? The segue is defined inside storyboard?

Comment: Yes SuperSigApproveTableViewController calls the alert view UIViewController* vc = [SignatureAlertViewController new];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
and I am trying to call a method after it get dismissed from [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[sp sendToPDF];}]; in the SuperSigApproveTableView